# Suppose that J and K are subgroups of G and that x; y are in G. Show that if Jx = Ky, then J = K.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $J$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and that $x,y \in G$. Show that if $Jx = Ky$, then $J = K$.

I'm struggling with this question for the case that $x \neq y$

Comment: I can see that if Jx=Ky then |J|=|K|.  x is in Jx and y is in Jx, x is in Ky and y is in Ky and Jx=Jy Kx=Ky. Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

$Jx=Ky\implies J=Kyx^{-1}$ let say $r=yx^{-1}$ Thus,$Kr$ is a group which is a right coset of $K$, which is only possible when $Kr=K\implies K=J$

Comment: I suppose you want to say 'which only possible when $Kr=K$, thus $K=J$'.

Comment: @GitGud :yes exactly.

Comment: But what you're saying is 'which is only possible when $K=J$ is a consequence of $Kr=K$'.

Comment: @GitGud: My english is not perfect,let me clarify What I mean.
After we see that $Kr$ is a group,we must require that $Kr=K$ which means that $K=J$

Comment: @GitGud It just depends how you parse it. Which is why we tell first years to use brackets...(Also, there was a sign on the the toilet door beside my office in the department where I did my PhD which read "Toilets for the use of female staff and postgraduate students only". I never quite worked up the courage to either add brackets or use the toilet...)

Comment: @user1729 A similar thing happened at my school. 'Toilet for teaching personnel and non-teaching personnel only'. In any case mathematics should always be read all at once, meaning that it should be bracketed as $[Kr=K\implies K=J]$.